# Remove object key from localStorage object variable without removing from localStorage

Tags: javascript

I need to remove object key from localStorage object variable without removing key from localStorage

```
let obj = localStorage;
let keys = Object.keys(localStorage).sort(function(a, b) {return a - b;});

for(let i = 0; i < keys.length; ++i){
    if (isNaN(keys[i])) {
        delete obj[keys[i]];
        keys.splice(i,1);
    }
}
```

code above removes non-numeric object key from **obj**  variable, but also key is removing from localStorage

How to remove key from localStorage object variable and keep that key in localStorage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved by using Object.values(localStorage) and obj.slice(i,1) instead of "delete" now i can safe remove keys from obj variable without removing localStorage keys and can get obj.length too.

```
let obj = Object.values(localStorage),
keys   = Object.keys(localStorage).sort(function(a, b) {return a - b;});
for(let i = 0; i < keys.length; ++i){
    if (isNaN(keys[i])) {
        keys.splice(i,1);
        obj.splice(i,1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you’re doing here is you’re copying the reference of the localStorage object and working on the localStorage itself
What you can do is instead of getting localStorage like this:

```
const obj = localStorage;
```

Do like this:

```
const obj = {...localStorage};
```

So what you’re doing here you’re copying the object by value and not by reference

Comment: Yes, it is cloning without reference, but now obj.length returns "undefined"